# Python taking paired string and integer input

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary, input

In this question they want you to take a paired string and integer input, like this:

```
4 that
3 be
0 to
1 be
5 question
1 or
2 not
4 is
2 to
4 the
```

https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/countingsort3

My issue is I can ignore the string, but I'm not sure how to make my code evaluate only the integer value without creating a dictionary because I want to order the set.  Is their an easy way to do this?  I had been using:

```
ar = [int(i) for i in raw_input().strip().split()]
```

for a list of integers, but for integer__string on multiple lines, what's the best way to evaluate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need ints as the problem is based on the count, a `collections.Counter` dict will count the letter for you:

```
Counter((raw_input().split()[0]) for _ in range(int(raw_input())))
```

That will get all the amount of times each "int" appears.

If you prefer a list:

```
 [raw_input().split()[0] for _ in range(int(raw_input()))]
```

which returns `['4', '3', '0', '1', '5', '1', '2', '4', '2', '4']` from the sample input.

```
10 <- n
4 that
3 be
0 to
1 be
5 question
1 or
2 not
4 is
2 to
4 the
```

If you want it ordered use sorted and cast to int:

```
sorted([int(raw_input().split()[0]) for _ in range(int(raw_input()))])
```

The `range(int(raw_input()))` is  *n, the size of the list ar*. which you need if you want all the data in a single list. You also don't need to strip when splitting.

If you do want a dict later:

```
data = dict(raw_input().split() for _ in range(int(raw_input())))
```

which would give you:

```
{'1': 'or', '0': 'to', '3': 'be', '2': 'to', '5': 'question', '4': 'the'}
```

Comment: so this would get rid of the words after the numbers, but still leaves me with the issue of maintaining the information associated with the attached words.  Would I be better off creating two arrays, one for numbers and one for words?

Comment: if you want both then use a dict, if you need to keep the actual order then use an OrderedDict, are the words actually relevant though?

Comment: Not in that exercise but I think that's the goal.  I appreciate all the help and hopefully this will get me further along.  I guess I need to review raw_input further!

Comment: @Rob, it is not a particular use case for raw_input! I would definitely recommend a dict if you want to pair data later

Comment: @Rob, I added a dict, it is just a matter of calling dict after splitting all the data

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate over the lines of input. I use the `iter(raw_input, '')` here, it will call `raw_input` repeatedly until it returns an empty string.
For each line, we strip it and split it once at whitespace. If there were any items on the line (a.k.a not only whitespace), we append the first space-delimited item on the line coerced to an integer, at the end of the array.

```
array = []
for line in iter(raw_input, ''):
    items = line.strip().split(None, 1)
    if items:
        array.append(int(items[0]))
```